# How to store primitive types dynamically in one property?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I'm pretty new to C/C++, usually, I code in C#, so I have a question:

```
enum PrimitiveType {
    BOOL,
    STRING,
    INT8,
    INT16,
    INT32,
    UINT8,
    UINT16,
    UINT32,
};


struct MyValue
{           
public:  
    String Id         
    PrimitiveType ValueType;        
    [???] Value;         
};
```

I want to store `int`s, `string`s and `bool`s in that `"Value"` property. 
In C#, I would declare `Value` as an object and cast the object to an `int` or `bool` like:

```
if(myValueObject.ValueType == BOOL)
    auto value = (bool)myValueObject.ValueType;
```

Which type can I use here in C++?

Comment: There's no language "C/C++".

Comment: you may use union type for this

Answer (score 5):

The canonical answer to that would be `std::variant`. I'd get rid of that enum then, though, as that introduces multiple sources-of-truth:

```
using PrimitiveValue = std::variant<bool, String, int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t>;

struct MyValue {
    String id;
    PrimitiveValue val;
};
```

If you absolutely need to produce that enum value, you'll need a mapping:

```
PrimitiveType MyValue::getPrimitiveType() const {
    if (val.holds_alternative<bool>()) { return BOOL; }
    else if (val.holds_alternative<String>()) { return STRING; }
    else if (val.holds_alternative<int8_t>()) { return INT8; }
    // else ...
}
```

Doing it this way ensures that there might never occur a state in which the type descriptor doesn't match the actually stored value, because the `variant` guarantees that.

That being said, your "C# way" of acting upon such value isn't the best option here. A much nicer one is [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) which together with the `overloaded` helper from that page can produce really concise code that acts differently depending on the stored value.

Comment: That sounds very good! The problem is that I have no variant type. I think it's because I'm working on an ESP32 with PlatformIO. Do you know which library I have to include to use a variant?

Comment: @Mr.Sheep This is a part of standard library starting from C++17. You need to `#include <variant>` and make sure that your compiler is running with C++17 enabled (e.g. `-std=c++17`)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentionned, `std::variant` is probably the best solution but you need C++17. If C++17 is an option, you can also use [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any).

If you're using a version anterior to C++17, I recommand using a [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) declaration.

Comment: Or `boost::variant` if available.

Comment: `boost::any` also exists